# Calories (capitalized) vs calories (lowercase)

Tags: alimentation, physique, science, majuscules

I noticed that Starbucks claims that it's small Java Chip drink has only "150 calories", in French - the lowercase version.

Is that supposed to automatically mean kilocalories, or, are they making a bogus claim on the energy loaded in this?

For even more fun, this is in the context of Quebec French. I'm also curious if there is a distinction between uppercase and lowercase versions in other regions' French, if there is any difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In both French and English, there are two units called *[calorie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calorie)*, with a lowercase C except as required at the start of a sentence. Which one is meant depends on the context.

- In a physics or chemistry context, a *calorie* (Fr.: *calorie*) is an amount of energy equal to 4.184 J, or (if indicated by the context) the amount of energy required to warm one gram of water by 1 degree Kelvin in certain temperature and pressure conditions. This meaning is sometimes disambiguated by specifying *small calorie* (Fr.: *petite calorie*).
- In a physiology or nutrition context, a *calorie* (Fr.: *calorie*) is an amount of energy equal to a *kilocalorie* (Fr.: *kilocalorie*), i.e. 1000 small calories. The SI prefix in the word *kilocalorie* forces the physics interpretation of the *calorie* stem. This meaning is sometimes disambiguated by specifying *large calorie* (Fr.: *grande calorie*). Occasionally, in both French and English, the word is spelled with a capital C, but this is not very common.

The Québecois [*Grand Dictionnaire terminologique*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/Resultat.aspx) lists both meanings under different subject headings, like the French [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/calorie).

Physical units, unlike French or English words, are case-sensitive; 1 cal is one small calorie and 1 Cal is one large calorie.

So from a linguistic point of view, “150 calories” (Fr.: “150 calories”) is correct to mean 150 kcal. It is not a bogus claim, but it can be viewed as purposefully unclear.

Answer (score -3):

Without sugar, a cup of coffee (150 ml) brings 2 kcal if ground, 4 kcal if in powder.

A lump of sugar (5 g) brings 20 kcal.

"*Only*" 150 kcal seems to mean that the cup is very large, and heavily sugared. It's about the consumption during half an hour of quick walking.

One needs, as an average, 2 500 kcal daily ; one single coffee covers more than 15% of this amount.

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: @Alexis Pigeon J'ai compris la question comme implicitement "Est-ce une fraude, si peu !", pas réellement une question d'unité (à laquelle Gilles a très bien répondu, n'omettant que de dire que l'unité légale est le Joule). Ma réponse était que c'est au contraire énorme.

Comment: My main question was about the units and capitalization, when used in the middle of a sentence.  
Still, it's fascinating to also learn about how little energy a standard coffee + 1 lump of sugar provides VS Starbuck's product!  I would recommend that the -1's be reversed because the insight on the nutritional value of coffee is also useful.

PS. "Java Chip" is definitely loaded with sugar, so the 150 Calories level makes sense.

Comment: Considering this is a Q&A site about the French language and its usage, it completely eludes me how this could be understood as a nutritional question, or why it wouldn't be immediately closed as off-topic if it were.

Comment: As this is French language Q&A, this is a bit of-subject, but people should stop believing that physical exercise will burn enough nutrient to make you slim down. If you are a couch potato you will have a hard time burning an additional 500 KJ in one hour. This is 30g of sugar. But you will build muscle that will burn Joules during the 23 hour of non-exercising.